# Error While Installing Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT)

Tags: installation, sql-server-data-tools

We've been trying to install SQL Server Data Tools and have experiencing an error preventing us from installing it and we can't figure it out.

We're installing it on Windows 7 Professional and already have VS 2015 and SQL Server 2014 successfully installed.

Here are the error messages that were included in the log:

```
Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80240025. Continuing...
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\Q041607\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64'
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\Q041607\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64'
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\Q041607\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64'
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409
Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\Q041607\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64'
Error 0x80072f08: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817291&clcid=0x409' to working path: 'C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64'
Failed to acquire payload: TSQLLANGSVC13X64 to working path: C:\Users\Q041607\AppData\Local\Temp\{020a3802-41bd-4140-a729-9b6daa142d10}\TSQLLANGSVC13X64, error: 0x80072f08.
Error 0x80072f08: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the machine your downloading from cannot get to the URL. You could speak to your network admins or the easier approach is to download the iso and install from that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

See the section on iso for the links you need.

This is from this forum post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1bfeabf-d37d-4748-b768-2802378f59ef/error-installing-ssdt?forum=ssdt

Comment: OK. Weird. Interestingly it worked perfectly on another computer which was apparently imaged the same way by IT. Anyway will try it and report back

Answer (score 3):

There is also a workaround by downloading and installing separately:

Microsoft.DataTools.Shared.vsix, Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix, Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices.vsix, Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.vsix

from:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

etc.

Or via Visual Studio 2017 -> Tools -> Get Tools and Features...

Answer (score 1):

**Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration** may be blocking site access.

Using IE, try navigating to the site in the error log. If **Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration** is blocking it, temporarily disable it for **Administrators**, and re-run **SSDT**.

**Server Manager**>**Local Server**>**Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration**